# Let A and B be intervals. Is A∩B an interval? What about A∪B?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How would you answer to this question in an exam?

My idea is that they can be both intervals or not. In fact, the intersection of 2 sets can give as a result an interval but also an empty set and the union of two sets can give as a result an interval (if the sets are equal) or two disjoint sets.

Do you agree with me? In case, how would you write an answer to such question in an exam?

Comment: typo: 2 disjoint INTERVALS

Comment: I made another mistake...We are considering the union and the intersection of 2 intervals, not sets. My answer is the same, either. The intersection of 2 intervals which, don't cover the same segment of the number line, is null. i.e [1,2] intersecate [3,4] = empty set, right? For the union we can make this example: (0,1) U (0,1) = (0,1), right? Of course, in other circumstances, we find an interval for the intersection and disjoint intervals for the union

Comment: It depends on how “interval” has been defined in your course. If it's defined as a convex subset of the real numbers, then the intersection of two intervals is a (possibly empty) interval; if it's defined as a *non empty* set to begin with, then the pair $(0,1)$, $(2,3)$ is a counterexample to both statements.

Comment: I understand that there are more ways to answer this question.Let's say, for example,that the answer that the prof. would like more is that the union of 2 intervals IS NOT an interval and he would prove that by a single counterexample - which is easy to find,of course. Let's say that the prof. uses a definition according to which the empty set is an interval too. Thus, the final answer would be that the union between 2 intervals is never an interval and the intersection between 2 intervals is always an interval.I find this answer strange.So, I am thinking about another reasonable way to answer

Comment: If I write (0,4) U (1,3) I get this interval (0,4), right?

Comment: Asserting that the union of intervals is never an interval is a quite dubious statement. `;-)` The correct statement is that the “union of two intervals *may not* be an interval”.

Comment: Ok! Thank you all! I wrote my answer and happy of that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a subset of the real numbers to be an interval it must satisfy that if $a,b \in I \quad a<b \implies c \in I ~ \forall a<c<b$.

So, $I_1 \cup I_2$ is not always an interval (consider $[0,1] \cup [2,3]$). But $I_1 \cap I_2$ is always an interval (even if it's empty). To show this take $x,y \in (I_1 \cap I_2)$ then, for any $x<z<y$, using that $x,y \in I_1$ and that $x,y \in I_2$ you get that $z \in I_1 \cap I_2$

Comment: If I write (0,4) U (1,3) I get this interval (0,4), right?

Comment: @MarioVald Sure, you need two intervals with empty intersection for that statement to fail.

Answer (score 4):

The intersection of any collection of intervals is always an interval. The union of two intervals is an interval if and only if they have a non-empty intersection or an open end-point of one interval is a closed end-point of the other.

[for more informations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics))

Comment: This assumes that you consider the empty set to be an interval, which depends on which precise definitions one is working from. (And if you do consider the empty set to be an interval, then, e.g. $\varnothing\cup[1,2]$ is an interval too, but doesn't match your "if and only if" condition).